# Component isn't re-rendering after state change in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

Let's say I have a link that, when clicked, adds a random number to an array in my state object called `queue`. The entire state.queue array is displayed on my page and gets updated as we click the link. I currently have a link that is supposed to be doing something similar but after my reducer alters the state (adds a new item to the array), my page isn't (re-?)rendering my component and so the page does not update.

What should I be doing to show the entirety of state.queue on my page, including dynamically updating as I click the link? Here's what I have:

**Channel.js**

```
class Channel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queue: [],
            // more initializations
        };
      ...
    }
    ...
    render() {  
        return (
            <div>
            {/*This part is never called because this.state.queue never has anything in it! */}
             {this.state.queue && 
                this.state.queue.length > 0 &&
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            {this.state.queue.map((queuedItem, i) =>
                                <li key={i}>{queuedItem}</li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>}


                <div>

                    <QResults
                        allQueryResults={this.state.queryState}
                        requestHandler={queueNewRequest}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const{queue} = state
    return {queue}
}

 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return ({
        queueNewRequest: (newRequestData) => { dispatch({type: newRequestData}) }
    })
} 

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps )(Channel))
```

**QResults.js**

```
export default class QResults extends Component {
    render() {
        const {requestHandler} = this.props

        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.allQueryResults.items.map((trackAlbum, i) =>
                    <li key={i}>
                        <a href='#' 
                        onClick={
                            () => requestHandler(trackAlbum.name)}>
                            Some link
                        </a>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

**actions.js**

```
export const QUEUE_NEW_REQUEST = 'QUEUE_NEW_REQUEST'

export function queueNewRequest(newRequestInfo) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: QUEUE_NEW_REQUEST,
            payload: newRequestInfo
        })
    }
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

function reducer1(state = {}, action) {
    ...
}

function reducer2(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUEUE_NEW_REQUEST:
             return {
                ...state,
                /*queue: [...state.queue,action.payload],*/ //compiler complains that 'TypeError: state.queue is not iterable'
                queue:[action.payload]
            } 
        default:
            return state
    }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    reducer1,
    reducer2
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.queue` refers to the state which is local to your `Channel` component. It is not the redux state. You initialize `this.state.queue` to an empty array, and then you never change it (ie, you never call `this.setState`).

If you want to interact with the state in redux, that's where mapStateToProps comes in. Since you've got a mapStateToProps that looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const{queue} = state
    return {queue}
}
```

The Channel component will get a **prop** named queue, and you can interact with it via this.**props**.queue.

So, the fix is to update Channel to interact with the prop. Most likely you'll want to delete this.state.queue, as it doesn't seem to serve a purpose and is causing confusion due to its name.

```
{this.props.queue && 
  this.props.queue.length > 0 &&
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.queue.map((queuedItem, i) =>
          <li key={i}>{queuedItem}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  }
```

Additionally, the way you've set up the root reducer has your redux state looking something like this:

```
{
  reducer1: {}, // not sure what this contains, since reducer 1 was omitted
  reducer2: {
    queue: [],
  }
}
```

So if that's really what you want your redux state to look like, your map state to props will need to be updated to this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {queue} = state.reducer2;
    return {queue};
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that will be very useful going forward but the issue I am having is that render() isn't being called after my reducer updates my redux state. So regardless of which queue I was referring to, I am unable to display any updates

Comment: @IsaacPerez you've set up your root reducer so that the data you want is accessible on state.reducer2.queue, not state.queue. So your mapStateToProps is always returning undefined. I've updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

Once you connected the `state` object to the `props` with `connect` you will get the returned objects in the `props`. See this: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return.

So, you just need to change `this.state.queue` to `this.props.queue` in your `Channel.js` file.

And your component is not rendering because it's not dependent on the changed `props`. So, doing the above-suggested change should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the responses about changing `this.state.queue` to `this.props.queue`, I needed to do a few things. Initialize queue in my `reducer2`:

```
function reducer2(state = {queue:[]}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUEUE_NEW_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                queue: [...state.queue,action.payload],
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Change mapStateToProps in **Channel.js**:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const{queue} = state.reducer2
    return {queue}
}
```